# AWS EC2 Postgres authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

1. I did setup Postgres-12 on Centos AMI EC2, It works well.
2. However, Sometimes (my case is the next day) I can not connect my DB by trying

   $psql -h XXXX -p5432 -Upostgres

A authentication failed error

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

3. Next, I change my postgres user again by

   $sudo su - postgres
   ~]$ psql -c "alter user postgres with password 'postgres'"

The connection login become work.

4. But sometimes it become not work again (same above authentication failed)
   I reset postgres password the same above command => The connection login become work.
5. It repeats #2

I don't know why. Does anybody know that? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the my Postgres use very much CPU (%CPU: 99%).
hat could be solution to this problem. I would appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you

[image]